# Distributing exp during encounters

Tags: dnd-4e, experience-points, encounters

When I get to distribute exp to party members, should I give the same amount of EXP to everyone or split it by monsters killed/fight contribution?

Comment: Just a note, since this is all new to you: though this has been marked as a duplicate, that's not a bad thing! Duplicates are good: they're appreciated by the site because they make it easier to find the answer by searching, and they're good for you because they quickly provide existing answers to your question. Cheers!